# Java Index out of bounds exception with dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, indexoutofboundsexception, path-finding, dijkstra

I keep getting this index out of bounds exception (at line 7 in code snippet) where I thought I clearly restrict the code from reaching out of bounds. If someone catches the flaw point it out please. (Note array is 2-dimmentional Object[36][25]). If needed I can post the rest of my implementation of dijkstra's algorithm, but this is where I believe the error is. All help is greatly appreciated.

```
    public void setNeighbors(Node N)    //adds neighbors to openNode and closedNode lists. if added to openNode calculate parent
{
    if(N.getX() < 36)   //keeps from checking out of bounds (Note isTilePassable() works properly)
    {
        if(!isTilePassable(nodeGrid[N.getX()+1][N.getY()].getX() * 32, nodeGrid[N.getX()+1][N.getY()].getY() * 32)) //east
            closedNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()+1][N.getY()]);
    }

    if(N.getY() < 25)
    {
        if(!isTilePassable(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()+1].getX() * 32, nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()+1].getY() * 32)) //south
            closedNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()+1]);
    }

    if(N.getX() > 0)
    {
        if(!isTilePassable(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()].getX() * 32, nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()].getY() * 32)) //west
            closedNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]);
    }

    if(N.getY() > 0)
    {
        if(!isTilePassable(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1].getX() * 32, nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1].getY() * 32)) //north
            closedNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1]);
    }

    boolean add;

    if(N.getX() < 36)
    {
        add = true;
        for(Node e : closedNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()+1][N.getY()]))
                add = false;
        }
        for(Node e : openNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()+1][N.getY()]))
                add = false;
        }
        if(add)
        {
            openNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()+1][N.getY()]);
            openNode.get(openNode.size() - 1).setParent(N);
        }
    }

    if(N.getY() < 25)
    {
        add = true;
        for(Node e : closedNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()+1]))
                add = false;
        }
        for(Node e : openNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()+1]))
                add = false;
        }
        if(add)
        {
            openNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()+1]);
            openNode.get(openNode.size() - 1).setParent(N);
        }
    }

    if(N.getX() > 0)
    {
        add = true;
        for(Node e : closedNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]))
                add = false;    
        }
        for(Node e : openNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]))
                add = false;    
        }
        if(add)
        {
            openNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()-1][N.getY()]);
            openNode.get(openNode.size() - 1).setParent(N);
        }
    }

    if(N.getY() > 0)
    {
        add = true;
        for(Node e : closedNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1]))
                add = false;
        }
        for(Node e : openNode)
        {
            if(e.equals(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1]))
                add = false;
        }
        if(add)
        {
            openNode.add(nodeGrid[N.getX()][N.getY()-1]);
            openNode.get(openNode.size() - 1).setParent(N);
        }
    }
```

Comment: By my count, this is line 7: `}`

Answer (score 0):

That is not strange - arrays in java start at 0 - so an array of size 36 will go from index 0 to index 35. Trying to get index 36 will be getting the object's 37th item, which does not exist.

```
if(N.getX() < 36)
```

In above line, x may be 35 (the max index) - and it will then try to get `N.getX()+1`=36 which is out of bounds. Same goes for the Y later on.